# How to write JSON response in Microsoft Excel using HP-UFT API Testing?

Tags: c#, hp-uft

I am currently creating an API test using HP-UFT. The purpose of this test is the make a call to an endpoint of a service and receive a JSON response with a list of items.

The values from the list of items must be added to a new Microsoft Excel sheet.

I searched on the internet and it seems that using C# this needs to be done.

Currently I've just got the full JSON and printed it in the Output.

```
public void RESTActivityV26_OnAfterExecuteStepEvent(object sender, STActivityBaseEventArgs args)
        {
            // Declare an empty bidimensional array to store transactions later
            String[,] transactionsArray = new String[100, 11];

            string responseBody = "not found";

            responseBody = RESTActivityV26.ResponseBody.ToString();
            this.Context.UserLogger.Info("The array: " + responseBody);
}
```

What should I do?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using C# or VBScript in uft?

Comment: @supputuri he told he is using API Tests in UFT, so he need to use C#.... Also the Code snippet is definately C#...